# How to wrap secret key from KeyStore by public key?

Tags: java, android, encryption

I'm interested in Android programming. I'm working with symmetric and asymmetric encryption and I wanted to wrap secret key from Android Key Store by public key but I failed. I'm able to get secret key from Key Store but I can't wrap it.

```
 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
 cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, publicKey);
 SecretKey secret = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey("key",null);
 byte[] encrypted = cipher.wrap(secret);
```

Error:

> InvalidKeyException:Cannot wrap key,null encoding

I tried to work with this key pair and secret key in code above - I successfully encrypted and decrypted some String by symmetric and asymmetric encryption.

What's interesting? I tried to generate new secret key by KeyGenerator and wrapping was successful. I'm little bit confused. I can't wrap it by secret key, which is loaded from KeyStore.

Could you help me please?

Comment: "I can't wrap it" is not descriptive enough. Are you getting an error?

Comment: Yes, InvalidKeyException:Cannot wrap key,null encoding

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you got this error while using [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) since I also just received this error.

I found that BouncyCastle is calling the following code which throws the error:

```java
byte[] encoded = key.getEncoded();
if (encoded == null) {
    throw new InvalidKeyException("Cannot wrap key, null encoding.");
}
```

The [Android KeyStore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore) won't allow you to access the value of the private keys and will instead return `null` when you try to do so, which is why the above error is thrown.